# jq query CSV output with name of 'this' thing

Tags: jq

example.json

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "name": "bob",
      "role": "gopherthis"
    },
    "baz": {
      "name": "tom",
      "role": "gopherthat"
    }
  }
}
```

example query:

```
jq -r '.foo[] | " \(.name),\(.role) " ' example.json
 bob,gopherthis 
 tom,gopherthat
```

My question is how do I get bar and baz associated with their name and role?  Where the output would be:

```
bar,bob,gopherthis
baz,tom,gopherthat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -r '.foo | to_entries[] | "\(.key),\(.value.name),\(.value.role)"' example.json
```

The output:

```
bar,bob,gopherthis
baz,tom,gopherthat
```

Comment: .key that was what I was looking for, thank you very much